# Jenkins multi-level folder project-based security - give access only to a specific subfolder

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I use jenkins project-based matrix security.

I have this folder structure (jenkins folders):

```
folder1/subfolder1A/jobA1
folder1/subfolder1A/jobA2
folder1/subfolder1B/jobB
folder2/subfolder2C/jobC
```

I can't seem to find a way to give access to a particular user *only to `subfolder1A`* or to `jobA2` etc.

I tried almost every combination of permissions, the only one that works *requires me to add the `job read`permission to the user for the root `folder1`*. The permission is inherited and they can now see *everything in `subfolder1A` and `subfolder1B`* etc.

If i don't do that, they see nothing. But If I do that, they have access to all subfolders of folder1 and all their jobs (with read permissions).

Do you know any configuration that would allow a user to access `only subfolderA or jobA1` ?

I use the latest jenkins 2.x (2.13 at the time of writing, I'll update to 2.14 possibly today)

Comment: I dont think you can achieve it without providing read access to the Root folder thus enabling the user to read all the jobs but build/configure only one specific job that he/she is interested in. You can achieve it using the Role Based Access control plugin in Cloudbees Jenkins. That's a paid plugin.Again, that's just my thought based on experience.

Comment: opened this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36788

Comment: Thanks. Added to my favs. I need an answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late to answer your question however this might be helpful for others.

You can give access up to one level deep to sub folders using [Role Based Access Control](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) plugin. In your case, assume if you want to grant an access to `subfolder1A` and restrict `all other sub-folders` then you can create `Project Role` and use following pattern:

```
folder1(/subfolder1A.*)?
```

Suppose, you want to provide access to both `subfolder1A` and `subfolder1B` and restrict other sub-folders, then use following pattern:

```
folder1(/subfolder1A.*|/subfolder1B.*)?
```

This will allow you to control nested folders up to one level.

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thank you. We were exploring permissions at sub folder level and glad found this.

Comment: I have different scenario. I have one folder under which different views (like tabs) and i want to assign build permissions to a particular group execute permissions under this view. How can i do that? like main folder -> view -> all jobs under this view